spring batch 5: how to NOT use the datasource?
I am migrating my spring boot spring batch application from spring batch 4.x to 5.1.1 (this is part of spring boot 2.7.18 to 3.2.4 migration).
In our batch application we do not use any spring batch internal table (that spring batch uses). On migrating to spring batch 5.1.1 the usage of these internal table seems to be the default behavior which I think was not the case in 4.x)
My Job Configuration looks like below -
@EnableBatchProcessing()
public class BatchJobConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public JobRepository JobRepository() {
        return new JobRepositoryImpl();
    }


   

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<BatchFileRecord> writer(@Value("#{stepExecution['jobExecution']}") JobExecution jobExecution) {
        ItemWriter<BatchFileRecord> writer = new BatchFileRecordItemWriter().withJobExecution(jobExecution);
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job processBatchFileJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return new JobBuilder(PROCESS_BATCH_FILE_JOB_NAME, JobRepository())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(step1)
            .end()
            .build();
    }


    @Bean
ItemReader<Pair<String[], Integer>> reader, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    public Step step1(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, ItemReader<Pair<String[], Integer>> reader,BatchFileItemProcessor processor, ItemWriter<BatchFileRecord> writer) {


        return new StepBuilder("step1", JobRepository())
            .<Pair<String[], Integer>, BatchFileRecord>chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .taskExecutor(executor)
            .throttleLimit(throttleLimit)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public JobLauncher JobLauncher() {

        ServiceJobLauncher jobLauncher = new ServiceJobLauncher();
        try {
            jobLauncher.setJobRepository(JobRepository());
            jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(executor);
            jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            systemLogger().error(COMPONENT_ID, "JobLauncherException",
                    "Failed to set Job Launcher properties" + e);
            appLogger().error(COMPONENT_ID, "JobLauncherException",
                    "Failed to set Job Launcher properties" + e);
        }
        return jobLauncher;
    }
}

In 5.1.1 as you can see in StepBuilder is now using JobRepository jobRepository and PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, which was not the case in 4.x.
On executing above job.
i am facing below error -
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'

Clearly Spring Batch 5.1.1 required datasourceBean. Is there any way to exclude/avoid datasource for spring batch?

Short answer no there isn't as that is needed to store the metadata for the job execution. The in-memory version has been removed. The longer answer you can use H2 if you only need in-memory support and don't care about the state or provide your own in-memory implementation.
